# Apache: Redirect with URL Pattern

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, query-string

I want an **.htaccess** (with mod_rewrite) file that when user type these URLs in the browser:

```
Example 1: http://sample.com/fix/abcd/v1/somequeryparams1
Example 2: http://sample.com/fix/efgh/v2/testqueryparams3
Example 3: http://sample.com/fix/ijkl/v3/anotherqueryparams5
```

It redirects them to this one:

```
Example 1: http://server.sample.com/fix1/fix2/fix/abcd/v1/somequeryparams1
Example 2: http://server.sample.com/fix1/fix2/fix/efgh/v2/testqueryparams3
Example 3: http://server.sample.com/fix1/fix2/fix/ijkl/v3/anotherqueryparams5
```

The fix parts are the same. But after fix folders, it has parameters.

I've tried these rules without success:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/fix/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://server.sample.com/fix1/fix2/%1 [R=302,NC]
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: @DusanBajic, Thank you for your attention. I've just updated the question.